# Работа с массивом объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив объектов, нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку, в этот массив записывался объект, а на повторный клик, удалялся из массива

```
function(post) {
  if (this.listFavorite.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.listFavorite.length; i++) {
      if (this.listFavorite[i].ID_dish === post.ID_dish) {
        //this.listFavorite.pop();
        this.listFavorite.splice[i, 1];
        i--;
        console.log("delete");
        break;
      } else {
        this.listFavorite.push(post);
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    this.listFavorite.push(post);
  }
}
```

Записываю объект нормально, но он не удаляется. пробовал через `.pop()`, работает нормально, но не подходит т.к удаляет с конца массива. Так же пробовал через `delete` но в массиве остается `undefined`. 
В функцию поступает объект такого вида:
[image: Объект]

Comment: CCмотри splice.

Comment: Пробовал делать через indexOf() но что-то не получилось..
Что не так с splice?

Comment: со splice все отлично. Просто ты не вызываешь эту функцию :-)

Comment: чтобы вызвать функцию `splice`, используйте круглые скобочки

Comment: Действительно..что-то я затупил жестко,спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Вы проверяете первый элемент, и если он не подходит - добавляете и выходите break из цикла. Я так понимаю если была задумка пересмотреть все элементы и добавить если его еще нет в массиве - то можно выделить к примеру бульку

```
function example(post, listFavorite) {   
    let listHaveElement = false;  

      for (var i = 0; listFavorite && i < listFavorite.length; i++) {   
        if (listFavorite[i].ID_dish === post.ID_dish) {
          listFavorite.splice(i, 1);
          i--;      
          listHaveElement = true;
          break;
        }
      }  
    if (!listHaveElement) {
      listFavorite.push(post);   
    }
  return listFavorite;
 }
```